# Cloud Foundry PUT / PATCH / DELETE

Tags: spring, cloud-foundry

I am trying to build a service broker. The service broker API requires the use of PUT / PATCH / and DELETE methods. I have a Spring Boot app, that implements the API. It works fine locally. But when I push it to my PCF account and try to test it there, I get 405 responses from the server. Is there a Spring Boot configuration setting that I am missing?

Comment: If it works fine locally, but not when you deploy to PCF then it would help to look at the parts that are different between your local env and your PCF env.  First thing that comes to mind would be that there are two layers of load balancing in front of the app (an external lb & gorouters).  I don't think the gorouter would make a difference here, but I suppose it's possible the external lb is prohibiting those methods? Can you confirm that the request is making it to your app & that the app is generating the 405, not something else?

Comment: Also, you'll want to bump up log levels and see if you can get more info out of Spring.  `org.springframework` is a good package to bump up the log level to DEBUG and get a ton of details about what's happening when the request comes into your app.